# Post request receives null value

Tags: php, android

I am developing a software wherein I send a post request to server (which is written in PHP) but the server receives null value. Any help would be appreciated.

Android and PHP files enclosed.

```
**This is my Android file:**
    public static JSONObject tosend = new JSONObject();
                            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                            {
                            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
                            jo.put("infoName", infoName[i]);
                            jo.put("infoNumber", infoNumber[i]);
                            jo.put("direction",direction[i]);
                            jo.put("version",version[i]);
                            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
                            ja.put(jo);
                            tosend .accumulate("introduceesJson", ja);
                            }
     String link = "http://172.65.45.7/checkAppInstalled.php";
                                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(link);
                                StringEntity se;
                                se = new StringEntity(tosend.toString());
                                // Set HTTP parameters
                                se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));
                                httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
                                httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "*/*");
                                httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "*/*");
                                //httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"); // only set this parameter if you would like to use gzip compression
                                //long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
                               /* HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(link);

                                List<NameValuePair> nVP = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                                nVP.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", tosend.toString()));

                                httpPostRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nVP));*/
                                //Log.e("Posted data", "TestPOST - nVP = "+nVP.toString());

                                // Hand the NVP to the POST



                                Log.e("posted data",tosend.toString());
                                HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);

                                if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
                                {
                                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                                    String jsonReceived = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                                   Log.e("result received",jsonReceived);
                                }
```

**Here's my PHP code:**

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonString, true);


if(!empty($jsonObj)) { 

foreach($jsonObj as $json){
   echo $json['infoName'];
   echo $json['infoNumber']; 
   echo $json['direction'];
   echo $json['version'];
}   
}
else
{
    echo "json empty";
}
```

**Here is the logcat result:**

```
04-02 15:34:07.882    9526-9704/com.thoughtrix.introduce E/posted data﹕ {"introduceesJson":[{"infoName":"Aa","direction":"2","version":"1","infoNumber":"96 35 874125"},[{"infoName":"Aa","direction":"2","version":"1","infoNumber":"96 35 874125"}]]}

Result Received :    json empty.
```

Comment: `se = new StringEntity(tosend.toString());` No need for `json=`

Comment: `the server receives null value`. Where? Which variable is null?

Comment: @Steve, if i dont use "json=", how am i gonna accept the request in php?

Comment: @Steve, for example, if(isset($_POST["what?"]))

Comment: @greenapps, in php, $jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input'); receives null value

Comment: @Sohail well i dont see you using `$_POST['anything']` in your code - you are accessing the raw input stream. If you are accessing the POST global, you need to edit your question to show that code

Comment: @Steve, so sorry. i was using it. i forgot that i deleted it and accessing the raw input. Even after deleting "json=",it didnt work

Comment: `$jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input'); receives null value –`. Do you mean that $jsonString==null ? Hard to believe. How do you know? What i can say for sure that $jsonString would never contain a valid json text in this way. So i rather think that after $jsonObj = json_decode($jsonString, true); that $jsonObj would be null.

Comment: Just do a `echo($jsonString);` to see what the content is.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing: The content is equal to the json text. Nothing else.

Comment: @greenapps, you're right. i tried echo($jsonString); . It receives the data i have sent. Now, the problem is $jsonObj = json_decode($jsonString, true); . when i echo($jsonObj) it returns E/result﹕ [ 04-03 10:37:28.512 17466:0x4446 D/Settings/BW ]
    ReadCodeTask:file size: 4096

Comment: Sorry but i really dont believe that that would be the echo. With a date time in it? file size? Please try again.

Comment: Dont know much from json but fiddled around a bit: Try this:    var_dump($jsonObj['introduceesJson']);
$jsonArray = $jsonObj['introduceesJson'];

foreach($jsonArray as $json){
echo("------\n");
   var_dump ($json);
    foreach ( $json as $jsonarray )
 {
      echo("              ------\n");
      var_dump ($jsonarray);

   echo $jsonarray['infoName'];
   echo $jsonarray['infoNumber']; 
   echo $jsonarray['direction'];
   echo $jsonarray['version'];

echo ("\n");
 }
 }

Comment: @greenapps,thumbs up. that did the trick. you're my hero. post the above as an answer. i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know much from json but fiddled around a bit: Try this:

```
var_dump($jsonObj['introduceesJson']);
$jsonArray = $jsonObj['introduceesJson']; 
foreach($jsonArray as $json)
  { 
  echo("------\n"); 
  var_dump ($json); 
  foreach ( $json as $jsonarray )
    {
      echo(" ------\n");
      var_dump ($jsonarray);
      echo $jsonarray['infoName'];
      echo $jsonarray['infoNumber'];
      echo $jsonarray['direction'];
      echo $jsonarray['version'];
      echo ("\n");
      } 
    } –
```

Could you please post the complete php script to extract all variables when you are done? I was puzzled...

Comment: $jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonString, true);

$arr = array();
 $jsonArray = $jsonObj['introduceesJson'];

Comment: foreach($jsonArray as $json)
 {
 foreach($json as &$item) 
 {
  if (is_array($item)) 
   {
    foreach($item as $key=>$value)
    array_push($arr, $value);
   }
 }
 }
print_r($arr);

Comment: Thanks. That does not print all values.  if (is_array($item)) { foreach($item as $key=>$value) array_push($arr, $value); } else var_dump($item); How to add to $arr too? Why the first ones come in differently?

Comment: yup dude . there is a problem. i dont know why the first ones come differently :(